# Sending sms app inside a Fragment

Tags: sms

I'm creating an android using fragments .I have created a an sms fragment for sending sms to a specific number but when it runs well but when i type the message then press send , the app crashes and closes. help me out.

```
public class SMS extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms, container, false);
        return v;

    }


    public void sendsms(View v)
    {

        //refernce the edittext
        EditText message=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Messege);
        //get the phone the number and the message

        String number="0712345678";
        String msg=message.getText().toString();
        //use the sms manager to send message
        SmsManager sm=SmsManager.getDefault();
        sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Messege sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}
```

the following is the xml layout that I have used.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/log"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send your feedback" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Messege"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="Enter your messege"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10" >

</EditText>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/send"
         android:onClick="sendsms"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Send SMS" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onClick() method is run in the UI thread. You don't want to send an SMS message from the UI thread. Try wrapping your sendSMS code in an AsyncTask or create a new Thread to run that code.